# Jqplot, multiple line type

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, jqplot

How do I make multiple line types in a single plot in jqPlot?

The following would display 3 lines in dotted, but what if I want line 1 to be dotted and line 2 to be solid?

```
plot = $.jqplot("myplot", [line1, line2, line3], {
    seriesDefaults : {
        linePattern : 'dotted',
        showMarker : false,
        shadow : false
    },
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it in [a similar way as they do it here](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/line-charts.html) in the bottom most example for marks you just need to specify your patter for each line accordingly.

[This jsfiddle show exactly how it is used.](http://jsfiddle.net/Boro/XcrZD/4/)

Comment: Your answer worked, I was actually trying this solution before, but something later in my code was nullifying the changes I made and I realized after. thanks